# How to change this foreach statement to only loop through twice?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using php I have the following:

```
foreach ( $matches[0] as $match ) {
...
}
```

How can I change the above statement to only loop twice then stop?

Thanks a bunch,

Comment: you could just extract the array slice you want to loop on

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Comment: Can you give an example of a for loop to run twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $matches[0] as $match ) {
    // Your code
    $i++;
    if ($i>1){
         break;
    }
}
```